# QDockWidget with QStatusBar possible?

Tags: qt, qt5, qdockwidget, qt5.3, qstatusbar

For a `QMainWindow` I can easily set a status bar. When I have a floating `QDockWidget`, it behaves like a normal window (from user's perspective).

What I want to archive is to add a `QStatusBar`to the floating `QDockWidget`. With the signal `topLevelChanged` I could hide the status bar when the window is docked.

But can I add a status bar to a `QDockWidget`? At least in the Qt Creator form builder I can not (I have a context menu "Create Status Bar" for `QMainWindow`, but not for `QDockWidget`).

Any way to do it a runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
QStatusBar *bar = new QStatusBar;//in constructor for example
bar->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
ui->dockWidget->setWidget(bar);
```

In this case `QStatusBar` will be as widget, but you can also use some QWidget as container and add layout where your `QStatusBar` will be always bottom.

With `QProgressBar`:

```
QStatusBar *bar = new QStatusBar;
QProgressBar *pr = new QProgressBar;
bar->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
pr->setValue(50);
bar->addPermanentWidget(pr);
ui->dockWidget->setWidget(bar);
```

Result(there is "Ready" too, but you can't see it because of size of my window) :

[image]

Little example with another part of your question:

```
QStatusBar *bar = new QStatusBar;
QProgressBar *pr = new QProgressBar;
bar->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
pr->setValue(50);
bar->addPermanentWidget(pr);
ui->dockWidget->setWidget(bar);

connect( ui->dockWidget,&QDockWidget::topLevelChanged,[=](bool visible)
{
    if(visible)
        bar->hide();
    else
        bar->show();
 });
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.